# Import.io, xpath expression, bgcolor attribute

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, import.io

I am trying to train import.io to grab data from inside a table, where one of the rows is formatted bgcolor #FFFFFF. The method I'm trying is Xpath.

In the example below it's the value '11' I want to grab.

Code snippet: `<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="RIGHT" class="txtBlackVerdanaBold10">11</td>`

I have tried :

```
SelectNodes(//*//td[contains(@bgcolor, 'FFFFFF')]/td"), and     
SelectNodes(//td[@bgcolor='#FFFFFF']/td").
```

Import.io returns **'the xpath is invalid'** in both cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Almost anything is possible, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Well actually i dont know where to start. Maybe its all about filtering out the data i dont want? I looked at Xpath and xreg but couldnt find anything useful there.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Ive rephrased the whole post, and hopefully its not that unclear this time. Looking for votes to reopen the question. @Parker

Comment: try this - (\d+)\1 - it should get the "11" in the capturing group you want.